# Accessing multi-dimensional array using a one-dimensional index in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3-dimensional array with dim = c(50,100,12). Now I want to access the grid point that corresponds to the one-dimensional index 123. I want to obtain a vector of 12 values from grid point 123. How do I achieve that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `as.vector(ThreeD)[123:134]` ?

Answer (score 2):

With R, you have a choice of indexing with arrays and matrices. You can use the dimensional indexing or you can use vector indexng. Just use:

```
myArray[123:(123+11) ]
```

Comment: So it wasn't an array. Terminology is important in these matters. It appears you intended (or at least should have intended) to say that you were accessing a nested list and that the index was c(3, 2, 1).

Comment: We can only guess at what "this" might have been. It would not be surprising if my suggestion failed with a list. It was designed to work with an array. Post a reproducible example if you are still having problems.

Comment: It is a nested list, right. It is one list of 12 lists with each of them containing one array.... That is why I tried climate[[i]][k][d,f,g]. Isn't it possible that way?

Comment: Not likely that way. Possibly `climate[[i]][[k]][c(d,f,g)]` but an example would be needed to be sure. Or you can post the results of str(.) on the object of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally solved the problem by converting the vector indices into array indices using the R base package implemented function arrayInd(ind, dim). It returns a two-dimensional matrix with the corresponding array indices that looks like that:

```
   [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  207  129
 [2,]  197  138
 [3,]  199  136
 [4,]  205  131
```